# Get content into class after other class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its possible to store text of a nested element in variable using jQuery? In my case, the content is 'SEO SEM'.

The only reference I have is the first class named `event_490` and I want to get the content of the child element with class `evcal_event_title` that is equal to 'Seo SEM'.

[image: Example image]

```
<div class="evo_lightbox_body eventon_list_event evo_pop_body evcal_eventcard event_489">
<div class="evopop_top" style="border-left-width: 3px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: rgb(33, 119, 189);">
<span class="ev_ftImg" data-img="http://localhost/academia/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/JBW2PXDOL6.jpg" data-thumb="http://localhost/academia/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/JBW2PXDOL6.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://localhost/academia/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/JBW2PXDOL6.jpg)"></span>
<span class="evcal_cblock " data-bgcolor="#2177bd" data-smon="junho" data-syr="2016">
    <em class="evo_date">
        <span class="start">11<em>jun</em>
        </span>
        <span class="end"> - 12</span>
    </em>
    <em class="evo_time">
        <em class="evo_day">jun 11</em>
        <span class="start">9:00</span>
        <em class="evo_day end">jun 12</em></em>
        <em class="clear"></em>
    </span>
    <span class="evcal_desc evo_info hide_eventtopdata " data-location_status="false">
        <span class="evo_above_title"></span>
        <span class="evcal_desc2 evcal_event_title" itemprop="name">Digital Stratety</span>
        <span class="evo_below_title">
            <span class="evcal_event_subtitle">09:00 - 18:00 | 16h | 155€</span>
        </span>
        <span class="evcal_desc_info"></span>
        <span class="evcal_desc3"></span>
       </span><em class="clear"></em>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the classes are not duplicated in the page you could just use class selectors `.` and `text()` function :

```
$('.event_490 .evcal_event_title').text();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, thanks in advance, the class="event_490" is unique, but the class="evcal_event_title" is not unique, i try your sugest but not work

Comment: Sorry it's my fault `->` should be `.` (updating my answer) check now please, _the class="evcal_event_title" is not unique_ in the page or inside `event_490`?

Comment: hey, my mistake, i call the class before click, sorry, and thanks works perfect :D thank u very much